# Expression must be modifiable ivalue for struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, compiler-errors, syntax-error

```
struct Vertex
{
    float Position[3];
    float Color[4];
    float TextCoords[2];
    float TexId;
};

static std::array<Vertex, 4> CreateQuad(float x, float y) {
    Vertex v;
    v.Position = { 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f };
}
```

this gives me error that the v must modifiable ivalue. and and the too many initializer value.

Comment: `Vertex v{};` would achieve the goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign a plain array with an initializer list, but you can assign a `std::array` that way:

```
struct Vertex
{
    std::array<float, 3> Position;
    std::array<float, 4> Color;
    std::array<float, 2> TextCoords;
    float TexId;
};

 static std::array<Vertex, 4> CreateQuad(float x, float y) {
    std::array<Vertex, 4> v;    
    v[0].Position = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    // fill the rest of v...
    return v;
}
```

Comment: is there a performence cost of using std::array like that. And also the i am just copying from this https://youtu.be/5df3NvQNzUs?t=991 video.

Comment: @Krinjon No, there's no extra cost. A `std::array` is just a plain array + some convenient helper functions.

Comment: and the code with plain array  works in that video. .

Comment: @Krinjon Could be a compiler extension. Do you know what compiler they use?

Comment: @ TedLyngmo  most probably msvc cause he is working in visual studio.

Comment: The time you link to in the video shows an array initialization (which is allowed; array assignment is not)

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo most probably msvc cause he is working in visual studio

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo   https://youtu.be/5df3NvQNzUs?t=1033 this is where he is assigning the array

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in MSVC either: https://godbolt.org/z/kDUfV8

Comment: @TedLyngmo : sorry about that, actualy he changed the array to vec3. But since he did not get any sqwigly line for error I thought he was running it fine. probably turned off the sqwiglies in visual studio. He did get error when he build it later in the video.

Comment: @Krinjon Ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign an array to an initializer list. That's why you get an error:

> error: assigning to an array from an initializer list

However, you can pass `std::initializer_list` to your constructor and copy its members to an ordinary array like:

```cpp
Vertex(std::initializer_list<float> const& position) {
    std::copy(position.begin(), position.end(), Position);
}
```

and then initialize like `Vertex v({ 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f });`.

However, I would suggest you using `std::array` instead of an ordinary array.